# Sound notifications in Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am trying to play an `audio` element in Opera 12.16 (the latest version right now) and [I noticed it doesn't work with `mp3` files](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1582462) but it does with `ogg` ones.

Here's my fiddle currently only with the mp3 file and NOT working on Opera:
http://jsfiddle.net/hMnsd/1/

The solution seem to do something like this (as pointed in [w3c website](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)):

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

I am using now this function to generate the sound:

```
function notificationSound(){
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', "http://"+ document.domain +"/files/notification2.mp3");
    audioElement.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');
    audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
    //audioElement.load()

    audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
    }, true);

}
```

In order to add the `ogg` file I've tried to generate the needed structure without succeed:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
var audioSource1 = document.createElement('source');
var audioSource2 = document.createElement('source');

//mp3 file
audioSource1.setAttribute('src', "http://"+ document.domain +"/files/notification2.mp3");
audioSource1.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');

//ogg file
audioSource2.setAttribute('src', "http://"+ document.domain +"/files/notification2.ogg");
audioSource2.setAttribute('type', 'audio/ogg');

audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');

audioElement.append(audioSource2); //opera
audioElement.append(audioSource1);

//audioElement.load()
$.get();
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    audioElement.get(0).play();
}, true);
```

How could accomplish it to make it work also in Opera with `ogg` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use feature detection instead of browser detection:

```
function isMpeg()
{
    var a = document.createElement('audio');
    return !!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;').replace(/no/, ''));
}


function isOgg()
{
    var a = document.createElement('audio');
    return !!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"').replace(/no/, ''));
}

function isAAC()
{
    var a = document.createElement('audio');
return !!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"').replace(/no/, ''));
}

alert(isMpeg());
alert(isOgg());
alert(isAAC());
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cy9AT/1/

Also see: http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html

Or Use [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would check which browser is user using and then select source.

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
if (navigator.userAgent.search("MSIE") >= 0) {
        audioSource1.setAttribute('src', "http://" + document.domain + "/files/notification2.mp3");
        audioSource1.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');
 } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") >= 0) {
     audioSource2.setAttribute('src', "http://" + document.domain + "/files/notification2.ogg");
     audioSource2.setAttribute('type', 'audio/ogg');
 } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") >= 0) {
     audioSource2.setAttribute('src', "http://" + document.domain + "/files/notification2.ogg");
     audioSource2.setAttribute('type', 'audio/ogg');
 } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
     audioSource1.setAttribute('src', "http://" + document.domain + "/files/notification2.mp3");
     audioSource1.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');
 } else if (navigator.userAgent.search("Opera") >= 0) {
     audioSource2.setAttribute('src', "http://" + document.domain + "/files/notification2.ogg");
     audioSource2.setAttribute('type', 'audio/ogg');
 }
 audioElement.setAttribute('autoplay', 'autoplay');
 audioElement.addEventListener("load", function () {
     audioElement.play();
 }, true);
```

I hope I understand your question correctly.