# Sound does not play in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I used a sound in my HTML page and wrote a JavaScript function to play it at a specific time. The problem is that when I load the page in PC, it works well, but on mobile the sound doesn't play. What is wrong?

```html
<audio id="buzzer" controls="controls">
<source src="assets/sound/buzzer.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

```js
function PlaySound1() {
    var audioElement = document.getElementById('buzzer');
    audioElement.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    audioElement.autobuffer = true;

    var source1 = document.createElement('source');
    source1.type= 'audio/mpeg';
    source1.src= 'buzzer.mp3';
    audioElement.appendChild(source1);

    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by mobile? iPhone, Android, Blackberry, etc? Which browser?

Comment: both android and iphone

Comment: Mobile audio needs a user interaction to start.  What's calling PlaySound1?

Comment: I have a countdown timer, when it reach 0 it should call PlaySound1()

Comment: Try triggering it off a click/touch event?  It's been a while, but I'm pretty sure it's enforced that some manner of human interaction is required to make the mobiles make the noises.

Answer (score 2):

Most mobile browser require direct, physical interaction to begin audio playback. Meaning you cannot trigger initial playback on page load or in any asynchronous function (like `setTimeout`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [UbaPlayer](https://github.com/brianhadaway/UbaPlayer), which comes with a Flash fallback for older browsers.

Support table (from [HTML5 Doctor: HTML5 Audio – The State of Play](http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/))

```
Mobile Browser                              Version         Codec Support
Opera Mobile                                11.0+           Device-dependent
Android                                     2.3+            Device-dependent
Mobile Safari (iPhone, iPad, iPod Touch)    iOS 3.0+        MP3, AAC
Blackberry                                  6.0+            MP3, AAC
```

Comment: useful article, as I figured out it depends on OS and browser, but anyway to be played on all of them?

Comment: I'd give UbaPlayer a shot.

Comment: I saw the link but do not understand how to use it, could you tell me more?

Comment: Download the zip https://github.com/brianhadaway/UbaPlayer/archive/master.zip and see the demo in index.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the table of browser support http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: so what to do? how can i play it on every browser? is it possible?

Comment: Look at this question[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791602/sound-notifications-in-opera/17798990#17798990](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791602/sound-notifications-in-opera/17798990#17798990)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code. By default mobile browsers will not autoplay sounds because the browsers creators don't want that to be exploited by websites. I pretty much gave up as well since I couldn't find anything online.

After 8 months or so, I switched from iPhone to Android and I found that both Chrome and Firefox have permissions options inside their browsers to allow a certain website to play sounds.

In iOS at the moment, I don't see such an option for Safari nor Chrome browsers.

I have attached pictures from Android Chrome browser settings:
[image: after clicking on the lock of the address bar]
[image: the hidden permissions settings]